# posicionar verticalmente

Tags: css

Como puedo posicionar los primeros 2  input uno debajo de otro, pero que esten **alineados**, lo que no permite que se alineen son las palabras que estan al lado izquierdo.

```css
.encima {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <div><span>nombre</span><input/></div>
    <div><span>pass</span><input/></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <div><span>nombre2</span><input/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

quiero obtener esto, pero no logro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que pruebes [esto](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) es bastante fácil de aprender a usar flex con esos ejercicios.

Comment: como dice el compañero @Edgar Gutiérrez, aprendete `"Flex-Box"`, te ayudará demasiado.

Answer (score 3):

Con:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Apilas las cajas una sobre otra y con:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Sobre los elementos contenedores hermanos, son **`div`**:

Ej:

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.encima {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  --ancho-del-texto: 5em;
}

.encima span{
  width: 15em;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.encima input{
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: var(--ancho-del-texto);
  width: calc(100% - var(--ancho-del-texto) - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <span>nombre<input/></span>
    <span>pass<input/></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <span>nombre2<input/></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Actualización

Teniendo en cuenta la actualización en tu **html**. Ahora es muy sencillo, simplemente y complementando la información anterior, ahora solo es necesario asignar un tipo de bloque al `<span>`, que pueden ser `display: inline-block;` o en tu caso por usar **flexbox**, sería `display: inline-flex;`

Sería así:

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.encima {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em; /*Esta no es necesaria, fue solo para separar un poco las columnas*/
}
.encima>div{
  padding: 0.1em; /*Esta tampoco es necesaria, es para separar las filas*/
}

.encima span{
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 4em; /*Con esto das un tamaño al span para que se alineen*/
}

.encima input{

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <div>
      <span>nombre</span>
      <input/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>pass</span>
      <input/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="encima">
    <div>
      <span>nombre2</span>
      <input/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actualice mi pregunta disculpas

Comment: No pasa nada, pero no entiendo, en la imagen actualmente tienes algo que si le das "**ejecutar**" a la demo lo obtienes.

Comment: pero estan desalineados por que puse palabras al costado

Comment: Si hay más elementos que no se reproducen en tu demo, es muy dificil saber que errores se te presentan, pero @hubman actualice mi respuesta, creo que así es lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta, puse palabras al costado

Comment: Okey, el reto es más difícil ya que el html esta mal maquetado, no debería ser así, el texto debería estar dentro de una etiqueta tipo **span**, **b**, **i**, pero igual si es posible pero con trucos css, nada prácticos en un proyecto real. Revisa nuevamente mi respuesta y me avisas si eso era.

Comment: si esta mal formado mi html puedes modificarlo a gusto con tal que este formado bien y sea mas simple

Comment: me ayudas con la edicion de mi html mas

Comment: edite mi pregunta con tu observacion de html, no se si ahora este bien formado

Comment: @hubman hasta apenas pude sacar tiempo, ya actualice mi respuesta, me avisas.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) es mas sencillo de estructurar y tener el control sobre tus elementos y no hace falta tampoco el añadir divs inecesarios:

```css
.general{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content:stretch;
  grid-gap:5px  20px;
}
.general>div{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
    <div><span>nombre</span><input/></div>
    <div><span>pass</span><input/></div>
    <div><span>nombre2</span><input/></div>
</div>
```

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Indicas que cada elemento ocupe 1 fraccion de las disponibles:

```
justify-content:stretch;
```

Obligas a los elemento a rellenar todo el espacio disponible

```
grid-gap:0px  20px;
```

Margen vertical de 20 px entre los elementos y 5px horizontal

al indicar:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
```

Significa el primer elemento ocupa 1 fraccion y el segundo elemento 2 fracciones por lo tanto es el doble:  1fr 3fr el triple, 1fr 4fr cutro veces mas grande, etc